# How do I make a <button> show a specific text in console.log when I click on the button?

Tags: javascript, html, button, logging, console

I've been coding for a week and I'm stuck on my online assigment where they want me to create a button that displays a text in console.log when I click on it. Been at it for 3 hours now checking different forums, youtube videos and topics but can't find a specific "simple" answer.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. Also consider [obligations before asking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593#261593).

Comment: Think this through> There are 3 things you need - an html button, a javascript console.log statement and an event listener that will connect the 2 together. Google those concepts

Comment: Always rely on the very good [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) for all things HTML, CSS and JavaScript. For example, here are some [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#examples)

Comment: @Kinglish - I will check event listener out - first time im hearing about it but we havent gone through it on the course yet. Thank you!

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thank you for that document - will take a look at it! Btw, is this the right way to reply to people? with a @?

Comment: Yes @Delamain2128

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function log() {
  console.log('Clicked');
};
```

```html
<button onclick="log()">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: I can't believe it was this simple. I knew it. You should have seen the massive wall-of-text codes I was pasting into VSC. Thank you very much for your help.